# Excel: Rename similar values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet of data with supplier names like below. The problem is the names have been spelt slightly differently.

```
 Column F
    GB - General Mills Uk
    General Mills Uk
    General Mills
    Eurostock Foods
    EurostockFoods
    INT - Eurostock foods
```

Is there anyway i can rename these suppliers to match like so:

```
Column F
General Mills
General Mills
General Mills
Eurostock Foods
Eurostock Foods
Eurostock Foods
```

To be honest i wouldn't even know where to begin here, although using vba i would imagine it would be something like this:

Loop through each cell in column F and see if the cell above is like the current cell, if true rename current cell to cell above...

```
    Sub FindMatchingValue()
        Dim i as Integer, intValueToFind as integer
        intValueToFind = ActiveCell.Offset(-1,0).Value
        For i = 1 to 500    ' Revise the 500 to include all of your values
            If Cells(i,1).Value Like intValueToFind then 
                Cells.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1,0).Value
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i
```

End Sub

This doesn't work and i need some help to get this to do what i need. I am brand new to vba so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Look into Fuzzy matching. It will be hard to match the different names without a standardized pattern.

Comment: You could probably use `InStr` to determine if each of the words in your desired name was in the slightly variant name and if so, perform a replacement based on that but it's not going to be too easy.  Search for Fuzzy Matching and it may be of use

Comment: you should have a look at this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: you could add another column B (on the right side of this column), and this columns you will write down the "Clean Names", like `General Mills` , `Eurostock Foods` and then use a loop and `Match` to replace all values in column A with the Matches in Column B ("Clean Names")

Comment: @ShaiRado how could i do this?